# Classes 'sticking' together

Tags: html, css, class

I'm trying to make a simple 1page responsive website in HTML5+CSS3, which will have a few sections underneath each other on one big scrollable page, like this:

```
Section 1
[content]

Section 2
[content]

Section 3
[content]
```

For some reason, while fixing the css of the "about" section, it seems to have gotten 'stuck' to the "connect" section below it (see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjc5znp3/)). It displays correctly on wide screens, but on narrow ones (like the one in jsfiddle will probably show) the "Connect" class will be placed underneath the image from the "About" section, i.e. on the right.

When I inspect-element the about and connect classes, they look weird too. Both of them seem to have lost their content, and the "connect" class thinks its content is above it instead of below?

I have no clue what I broke, but it seems like maybe I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML

```
<div class="about">
    <header>
        <h2 id="about">About</h2>
        <hr>
    </header>

    <div class="aboutContainer">
        <div class="aboutText">
            <p>Text text text</p>
        </div>

        <div class="aboutImg">
            <img src="img/about_photo.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="connect">
    <header>
        <h2 id="connect">Connect</h2>
        <hr>
    </header>

    <div class="links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo1.png" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo2.png" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo3.png" /></a></li>
        </ul>                       
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.aboutContainer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.aboutText {
    display: inline;
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}

.aboutImg {
    display: inline;
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}

.aboutImg img {
    min-width: 240px;
}

.connect {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.links {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
}

.connect ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.connect li {
    display: inline;
}

.connect img {
    display: inline;
    width: 32%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following before `connect` div.

```
<div class='clearfix'></div>
```

And following css:

```
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

Hear is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjc5znp3/1/)

Comment: Thanks Bongs! That does take care of the positioning beautifully, however the about and connect class still seem to be 'empty' (inspect element -> hover over <div class="about">...</div> and <div class="connect">...</div>. the dimensions in pixels will not include their contents, and in the connect class seems to be empty completely (0px x 0px) ). Since I have a "gallery" class above these two that does seem to behave and include its content, I'm worried these two might still be broken somewhere?

Comment: It is because you have floating element inside `content` div, which you need to handle carefully. I would recommend you to use front-end framework like twitter-bootstrap. I've moved the `clearfix` inside `connect` and changed the css of `connect` - `display: block;`. Check it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I found that if the `float: left;` is put in the parent class (i.e. `.about` and `.connect`), it will show up as containing the proper content :) As for moving the clearfix... it's currently in `about`? Seems to mess things up for me. What would be the added benefit of moving it inside `connect`?

Comment: If you've floating element, the parent too need to have float property. Somewhere it need to be cleared. Can't explain much in comments.